# Android Studio, getResource(relativePath) in standalone project vs a module?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

I have the following in a module called "myParser" in my android project.  It is a regular java module, not an "app" module.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
}
```

project dir is: src/main/resources.  I created directories "firstSet" and "secondSet" under src/main/resources.

src/main/java/com.parser/MyParser.java

MyParser.java:

```
public static Reader getFileReader(String subdirectory, String filename) {
    String path = subdirectory +"/" + filename;
    FileReader reader = null;
    try {
    URL url = MyParser.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path);
    String path = url.getPath();
    File resourceFile = new File(path);
    reader = new FileReader(resourceFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return reader;
   }
```

I debug a test in the same module(src/test/java/com.parser/MyParserTest.java"), path is "firstSet/hello.txt" and url is null.

But if I replicate this module inside intellij as a STANDALONE PROJECT, url is "file:/Users/marccampbell/GradleProj/build/resources/main/firstSet/hello.txt" when I debug the same test(also in src/test/java/com.parser)

Why can't it find the file?  I ultimately want to use this module to read this resource file, from my android app, within the "app module".  I have already set up the "app" module to be dependent on the "myParser" module